# Is polling API are supported in message hub or not?

Tags: message-hub

i'm new to LoopBack connector development. could anyone please help me with what is inbound support,outbound support and what is polling API .

Answer (score 2):

IBM MessageHub offers two interfaces, a REST one for low throughput applications, and the full Apache Kafka 0.10.0 API. 
For using the Kafka API, you can use the official Java clients, or any client that supports authentication over SASL/SSL, e.g. JavaScript and Python clients based on librdkafka (on Linux and Mac).

There are no specific LoopBack modules for Apache Kafka AFAIK.